# Handlebars templates rendering in DOM before compiling

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, marionette

I recently noticed that in my Backbone Marionette app, some of my API calls are taking longer than expected. In my network tab, I'm seeing image requests for things like `%7B%7Bavatar%7D%7D` and `%7B%7Blogo%7D%7D`. These requests are taking upwards of 7 seconds.

In my handlebars template for this page, I have something like `<img src="{{avatar}}"/>`
My best guess on what is going on is that my Handlebars templates are getting inserted into the DOM before they are compiled so the DOM is requesting things like {{avatar}} and {{logo}} rather than the actual path to the images.

I've include the following prototype in my initializer to handle all of the Handlebars compiling.

```
Backbone.Marionette.TemplateCache.prototype.compileTemplate = (rawTemplate) ->
  Handlebars.compile(rawTemplate)
```

Besides this image issue, I haven't had any other problems with compiling my templates this way. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this problem or at least where to start looking?

Comment: How are you including your templates in the page? Hidden `<div>`s or `<script type="text/html">`?

Comment: I'm including my templates as JS strings under window.Templates

Comment: Can you produce a minimal example of the problem? I'm guessing that your JavaScript is being interpreted as HTML somewhere, possibly a missing `type` attribute, quoting issue, ...

Comment: Well part of the issue is that I'm not exactly sure what is causing the problem. Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing in the network tab: http://grab.by/nxXA

Comment: And that's why you need to rip out everything except what's needed to demonstrate the problem: if you rip out all the noise, the root of the problem will be easier to see. Somewhere your template is being treated as HTML, that's about all I can say with the limited information at hand.

Comment: I'm just starting to learn Handlebars so would like to see the problem illustrated better as well.  Here is a jsFiddle you can fork to build a minimal test case.  The process of building a minimal test case will often lead you to the answer.  Start with a known maximum test case and start stripping out features until you arrive at the minimal test case.  http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/M5J8Q/